# Using ajax to load a jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying (and failing) to load a jQuery DataTable using the built-in ajax source argument.  The datatable, however, shows the message "Loading..." where the row(s) should be appearing.

Here's my datatable call :

```
    $('#my-table').dataTable( 
             {bFilter: false,
              bInfo: false,
              bJQueryUI: true,
              bPaginate: false,
              bStateSave: false,
              bSort: false,
              aoColumns: [ {"sTitle" : "Date"}, 
                           {"sTitle" : "Our Co."}, 
                           {"sTitle" : "Their Co."}, 
                           {"sTitle" : "Note"} ], 
              sAjaxSource: "/contact/company_name/"} );
```

Using Chrome, I can see that the call to `/contact/company_name/` is occurring, is returning status 200, and has the following data: `[[[Hello], [Goodbye], [Test1], [Test2]]]` (which is my test data).

I can also see that the dataTables.min.js is returning the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

I assume that my returned data is not formatted properly.  Can anyone suggest the solution?

Comment: Is `[[[Hello], [Goodbye], [Test1], [Test2]]]` the exact content returned by the ajax source?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

according to the [website](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/ajax.html)
your service should return data in this format:

```
{
  "aaData": [
    [
      "row 1 col 1 data",
      "row 1 col 2 data",
      "row 1 col 3 data",
      "row 1 col 4 data"
    ],
    [
      "row 2 col 1 data",
      "row 2 col 2 data",
      "row 2 col 3 data",
      "row 2 col 4 data"
    ],
    [
      "row 3 col 1 data",
      "row 3 col 2 data",
      "row 3 col 3 data",
      "row 3 col 4 data"
    ],
    [
      "row 4 col 1 data",
      "row 4 col 2 data",
      "row 4 col 3 data",
      "row 4 col 4 data"
    ]
  ]
}
```

so, wrap your array in an object, name the array as `aaData` and try again.
or you can name it any way you like, but then you need to add the `sAjaxDataProp` parameter in the datatables initialisation (say you name it `data` you would do it like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/ajaxsource/callmydata",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "data"
} );
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am actually an idiot, having solved this *exact same* issue last week.  This was the reminder I needed.

Comment: The link at the top is broken as of October 1, 2014

Comment: I do believe [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) was the page linked to.

Comment: how can i add aoColumns also !

Answer (score 6):

If your ajax source returns

```
[[[Hello], [Goodbye], [Test1], [Test2]]]
```

This is not ok for datatables. It should be:

```
{
     iTotalRecords: "54",
     iTotalDisplayRecords: "22",
     aaData: "[['Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Test1', 'Test2']]"
}
```

aaData stands for array of arrays.