# Jquery Datatables populate after form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to do a form submit (POST) with some parameters and based on the parameters I want to populate my datatable. But I'm not very good with Javascript (My language is Java), so I'm trying to do it with an Ajax call. But it won't work for me. Everything works for me, except doing a POST with parameters to the servlet. The datatable always populate automatically, but it should populate after the form submit.

Does someone know an example of my case? I read a lot of form posts here and tutorials, but none of this case (?).

My code is now as follows, this works for me. Except I can't sort or search anymore in this table. What is missing?

Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/global/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/global/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
  <label for="season">Season:</label>  
  <input type="text" name="season" id="season" value=""/> <br />
  <label for="type">Type:</label>  
  <input type="text" name="type" id="type" value=""/> <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search"> 
</form>

<table class="display" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>NationId</th>
      <th>RegionId</th>
      <th>Attendance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- data goes here -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $("#btnSubmit").click( function() {
    var formData = "season=" + $("input#season").val() + "&type=" + $("input#type").val();
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bDestroy": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "/servlets/service/competitions/",
      "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
        oSettings.jqXHR = ${esc.d}.ajax( {
          "dataType": 'json',
          "type": "POST",
          "url": sSource,
          "data": formData,
          "success": fnCallback
          } );
      }
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: have you looked at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629423/using-ajax-to-load-a-jquery-datatable

Comment: Hmm.. dat is not my problem. My servlet returns already data and this data is filled in the DataTAble. However, I cant sort or search anymore in that table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, this is the full answer for you question

You need to make three events, the first load the database information in your datatable, the second event inserts the new information on the database, and the third refresh the datatable content.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/global/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/global/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Global variables 
var otable;
var dataTab;
$(document).ready(function () {
    chargeData();
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
       insertData();
    });   
}); 

// 1. charge all data 
function chargeData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //create a method for search the data and show in datatable
        url: "/servlets/service/competitions/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{ }',
        dataType: "json",
        success: AjaxGetFieldDataSucceeded,
        error: AjaxGetFieldDataFailed
    });
}

function AjaxGetFieldDataSucceeded(result) {
    if (result != "[]") {

        dataTab = $.parseJSON(result);
        //instance of datatable
        oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aaData": dataTab,
            //important  -- headers of the json
            "aoColumns": [{ "mDataProp": "season" }, { "mDataProp": "type" }],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
            "bJQueryUI": true,

        });

    }
}

function AjaxGetFieldDataFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}

// 2. this function only insert the data in your database
function insertData() {
    var email = $("#season").val();
    var evento = $("#type").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //in this method insert the data in your database
        url: "/servlets/service/competitions/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{ season : "' + season + '", type : "' + type + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: AjaxUpdateDataSucceeded,
        error: AjaxUpdateDataFailed
    });
}

function AjaxUpdateDataSucceeded(result) {
    if (result != "[]") {
        alert("update ok");
        refreshDatatable();
    }
}

function AjaxUpdateDataFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}

// 3. This function refresh only the datatable not all page  in varius events you can call like INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ;D
function refreshDatatable() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //same event used in chargeData function
        url: "/servlets/service/competitions/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{ }',
        dataType: "json",
        success: AjaxRefreshDataSucceeded,
        error: AjaxRefreshDataFailed
    });
}

function AjaxRefreshDataSucceeded(result) {
    if (result.d != "[]") {
        var jposts = result;
        dataTab = $.parseJSON(jposts);
        //when the instance of datatable exists, only pass the data :D
        oTable.fnClearTable();
        oTable.fnAddData(dataTab);
    }
}

function AjaxRefreshDataFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}

<script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="">  
  <label for="season">Season:</label>  
  <input type="text" name="season" id="season" value=""/> <br />
  <label for="type">Type:</label>  
  <input type="text" name="type" id="type" value=""/> <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search"> 
</form>

<table class="display" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SEASON</th>
      <th>TYPE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- data goes here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the format that you are expecting on `result` ? I'm having a really hard time to fix my code, and I think your answer is what I need, I just can't figured out how to solve this.

Comment: the ajax request return json string.  if you use .net is something like this  result.d  -->  dataTab = $.parseJSON(result.d);  and Works!!

Comment: This should be plastered all over the internet. You've saved me quite a bit of headbanging. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here the data is passed as string(formData) in ajax function and by default ajax expect the json object. Passing data in string can be done in two ways

1) Append the generated query string to the url

```
     oSettings.jqXHR = ${esc.d}.ajax( {
           "dataType": 'json',
           "type": "POST",
           "url": sSource + "?" + formData, /*  here url need be proper, as url can have some query string params in that case it shoukd be join with "&" not "?" */
           /* "data": formData, no need to have data config then */
           "success": fnCallback,
           "processData": false
          } );
```

2) when data is already serialized into string then set processData flag to false in ajax

```
oSettings.jqXHR = ${esc.d}.ajax( {
          "dataType": 'json',
          "type": "POST",
          "url": sSource,
          "data": formData,
          "success": fnCallback,
          "processData": false
          } );
```

Comment: Hmm.. dat is not my problem. My servlet returns already data and this data is filled in the DataTAble. However, I cant sort or search anymore in that table. Tonight I will post the response in the first post, so you can see that the response is right (I think so)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same functionality as you. The way I approach things though is a little bit different.

What I do ...

```
<input type="text" id="searchCondition"/>

<div id="container">
  <div id="ajaxDataTable"></div> 
</div>
```

On document.ready I call the ajax function to get me the datatable passing the value of searchCondition to my servlet. The result (THIS IS JUST THE TABLE) is put in the ajaxDataTable div. On success of the ajax command, I do the normal initializations on the datatable.

Now on any search, I call the same ajax command and pass again the search condition.

Works fine for me!