# Facing issues while displaying json data with jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am new to jquery datatables. I have a json format returning from the server in the below format:

```
{
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://hostname:port/state/city/1"
    }
  ],
  "name1": "value1",
  "name2": "value2",
  "name3": "value3",
  "name4": "value4"
```

}

In the javascript I am using the below code to display in the table:

```
<script>
  $(function  ()  {
    $('#dataTable').dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "sAjaxSource": "partials/records.txt",
      "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "name1" },
        { "mData": "name2" },
        { "mData": "name3" },
        { "mData": "name4" },
      ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

I am getting error and the data is not getting displayed in the table. How to display the above json format in the datatable? To my limited knowledge, I see that I do not have `"sAjaxDataProp": "list",` in the script? Is the error because of the `sAjaxDataProp` property?

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my query. The format of the json should is not correct. The json should contain `sAjaxDataProp` value. The json should be formatted before it is consumed by the datatable. Details can be found in the below link: [Using ajax to load a jQuery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629423/using-ajax-to-load-a-jquery-datatable)